# Search by tags with relevance

Tags: mysql

I couldnt find anything like this

I have Sql tables

```
tag (tag_id, tag_name..)
tags (id, tag_id, post_id)
```

Example:

```
table: tag
1 New York
2 Madrid
3 Paris
4 London
```

if I have tags table populated in a manner that some posts contains 0,1,2,3 or many tags, how to make sql with search order to get result sorted by number of tags that post contains ? Like a "best match" search..

For example if I search for 3 tags "New York", "Madrid", "Paris"

the expexted result should be>

```
Post_id's:  1,4,6,   2,3,5,   9
Where show first
    1,4,6 (has all 3 searched tags)
    then
    2,3,5 (has 2 searched tags)
    then 
    9 (with 1 searched tag)
```

Comment: You should include much more example data (table post and table tags) is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tags.post_id, COUNT(*) AS match_count
FROM tag
JOIN tags ON tag.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE tag.tag IN ('New York', 'Madrid', 'Paris')
GROUP BY tags.post_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, tags.post_id ASC;
```

Gives these results:

```
+---------+-------------+
| post_id | match_count |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           3 |
|       4 |           3 |
|       6 |           3 |
|       2 |           2 |
|       3 |           2 |
|       5 |           2 |
|       9 |           1 |
+---------+-------------+
```

With this data:

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
    tag_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tag VARCHAR(40)
);

INSERT INTO tag VALUES
(null, 'New York'),
(null, 'Madrid'),
(null, 'Paris'),
(null, 'London');

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tag_id INTEGER,
    post_id INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tags VALUES
(null, 1, 1),
(null, 2, 1),
(null, 3, 1),
(null, 1, 4),
(null, 2, 4),
(null, 3, 4),
(null, 1, 6),
(null, 2, 6),
(null, 3, 6),
(null, 1, 2),
(null, 2, 2),
(null, 1, 3),
(null, 2, 3),
(null, 1, 5),
(null, 2, 5),
(null, 1, 9);
```